# Python generically parse data into object structure

Tags: python, parsing, generics, data-structures, struct

What I want to know is if I have a defined structured object with known parameters and a known order. I want to parse a binary blob into this structure in a generic way.

For example, I know that my file is a binary file of this structure

```
typedef struct { 
         uint     frCompressedSize;
         uint     frUncompressedSize;
         ushort   frFileNameLength;
         ushort   frExtraFieldLength;
         char     frFileName[ frFileNameLength ];
         uchar    frExtraField[ frExtraFieldLength ];
         uchar    frData[ frCompressedSize ];
     } ZIPFILERECORD;
```

Is there a better way to do this than reading in individual fields at a time in a hard coded manner? In my real code the structure has almost 100 parameters so the hardcoded method is not my first choice.

Any Ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the python [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) library

Comment: This got me half way there, I had to break up the structure into two parts, since the last 3 parameter sizes relied on the values read in on the top paremters. Dividing it up into several struct.unpack calls solved my problem in much less than the hardcoded parsing I thougth I was going to have to do. thanks!